# How i upload data from internet in sas?

Tags: sas

I have a data set:

```
"Country" "Year" "GDP.per.capita" "Infant.Mortality.Rate"
"Argentina" 1950 6252.85859891315 68
"Australia" 1950 10031.1213832996 25.1
"Austria" 1950 5733.09811393918 66
"Belgium" 1950 7990.46583983014 53
"Benin" 1950 1104.46653022144 204.8
"Burkina Faso" 1950 515.707854373329 178.7
"Canada" 1950 10581.265520182 41.2
"Chile" 1950 3713.9960324847 147.7
"Colombia" 1950 2087.94941987793 124
"Denmark" 1950 8996.05428012913 29.1
"Finland" 1950 5845.6263157204 44
"France" 1950 7104.00732497357 47.6
"Ghana" 1950 943.100536353646 150.1
"Greece" 1950 3040.41319387776 35
```

I wrote a script to upload this data from the internet but it doesn't work. this give me a bug that GDP is not a veriable. I even don't undarstand the bug.

```
FILENAME RegProj URL "http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Long.txt" ;
DATA book;
length country $20;
INFILE RegProj firstobs=2 dlm=" " LRECL=131072 dsd truncover;
INPUT Country$ Year GDP.per.capita Infant.Mortality.Rate;
RUN;
```

Comment: You can't use dots in the variable names.  Change the dots to _.  They don't have to match the online names perfectly - they can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your variables to be legal SAS variables, and you're fine.

```
FILENAME RegProj URL "http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Long.txt" ;
DATA book;
length country $20;
INFILE RegProj firstobs=2 dlm=" " LRECL=131072 dsd truncover;
INPUT Country$ Year GDP_per_capita Infant_Mortality_Rate;
RUN;
```